# Function modifying argument Julia

Tags: julia

I have a mutable composite type,

```
 mutable struct MyType

      x::Array{Float64}

 end
```

And I have a function which I would like to modify it in place,

```
 function f(z::MyType)

      newx = z.x + 1
      z.x = newx

      return z

 end
```

This does not seem to work to update z.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`z.x` is an array so one must write `z.x .+ 1` (note the extra dot) to indicate element-wise addition.

```
function f(z::MyType)
      newx = z.x .+ 1
      z.x = newx
      return z
 end
```

This function *does* update `z`:

```
julia> z = MyType(rand(1:10, 4))
MyType([10.0, 7.0, 2.0, 2.0])

julia> f(z)
MyType([11.0, 8.0, 3.0, 3.0])

julia> z
MyType([11.0, 8.0, 3.0, 3.0])

julia> @btime f($z);
  886.115 ns (4 allocations: 208 bytes)
```

The allocations are (at least) understood from the fact that it allocate a new array `newx` (a copy of `z.x` where every element is increased by one) which is then set to be the new array assigned to `z.x`. The original array, which was assigned to `z.x` before, is now lost (and will be gc'ed).

What you presumably want to do is modify the array that is assigned to `z.x` in-place without creating an intermediate array. This can be achieved by writing

```
function f(z::MyType)
      z.x .= z.x .+ 1 # or equivalently z.x .+= 1
      return z
end
```

Note the `.=` instead of `=` which assigns in-place (you can think of an elementwise assignment). This gives

```
julia> @btime f($z);
  372.284 ns (2 allocations: 48 bytes)
```

Note that you could write this much shorter as well

```
f(z::MyType) = (z.x .+= 1; z)
```

Comment: I know about that - this was just example code to show that I was making an update (the operation I am doing is much more complicated). But the issue is not that the RHS is not the correct expression, it's that it is not updating the object.

Comment: Your example is too minimal than because it _does_ update the object (after you add the extra dot). I suggest you provide a minimal example that actually shows the "broken" behavior.

Comment: I refactored my answer quite a bit. Maybe this helps. Nonetheless, both approaches update `z`. One is just more efficient in doing so.